# Can I change Cortana's voice?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Don't really dig the voice, I prefer a voice similar to that of Mr. Siri, like British English. Is there any way to change the voices?

Comment: Looks like you [can give her a British accent](http://blog.laptopmag.com/change-cortanas-voice-windows-10), but not sure if you can force a gender change on her yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[More details and pictures here](http://blog.laptopmag.com/change-cortanas-voice-windows-10)

1. Navigate to Settings. Click "Time and Language" and then choose "Region and Language" on the left.
2. Select a new region.

   - Cortana is currently only available in the US, UK, Italy, France, Spain, Germany, and China.*
3. Add the local dialect for the appropriate language.
4. Click the language you added and set it as the default. Then, click options. Download the *language pack* and *Speech*.
5. Click "Settings" under *Speech*. Select the new language.
6. Check "recognize non-native accents for this language".
7. Reboot your computer and set up Cortana again.

### Optional

- Change your keyboard back to the old layout if you like that better. You can do this by clicking the button left of the system clock.
- Change the date format back. Search for "Region" in the search box and click "Region - Control Panel". Select your original region from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey Lin's answer, while useful, doesn't actually change the sound of the voice (this option may not have existed at the time of his writing). To change how Cortana sounds, not just its language, do the following:

1 Open Start -> Settings -> Time & Language -> Speech

2 Scroll to "Text-to-Speech"

3  Change the text-to-speech voice to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you still get stuck.

Settings -> Cortana -> Talk to Cortana -> Change the setting on the "Cortana Language".